# Shor's algorithm - why doesn't the final collapse of the auxiliary qubits cripple the computation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, causality, algorithms

Let's look at quantum subroutine of [Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor's_algorithm) (image [source](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.2724)):

> [image]

1. Hadamard gates create superposition of all (exponential number) values for input qubits.
2. Then we perform a classical function on them, which is here: $f(a) = y^a \textrm{ mod } N$, where $N$ is the number we would like to factorize, $y$ is some chosen (usually random) number smaller than $N$.
3. Then we perform measurement of value of this function $f(a)=m$ (random). **This measurement restricts the original ensemble** to only input values $a$, such that $f(a)=m$.
4. Mathematics says that this restricted ensemble has to be periodic, this period can be concluded from value of (quantum) Fourier transform, and allows to conclude the factors.

However, quantum computers require reversible/unitary operations, e.g. we cannot just use OR gate: $(x,y) \to x\ \mathrm{or}\ y$, and instead we need to use e.g. $(x, y, z) \to (x, y, z\ \mathrm{xor}\ (x\ \mathrm{or}\ y))$, which is own inverse $-$ but which requires one **additional auxiliary qubit** initialized as $z=0$. So their required number is comparable with the number of gates of the classical function - can be quite large.

**But what's happening with all these auxiliary qubits at the end of computation, and after the computation is over?**

Measuring the classical function has led to the crucial restriction of the original ensemble - can we ensure that auxiliary qubits aren't finally also measured/collapsed, also restricting the ensemble?

Is there some time interval when such measurement restricts the ensemble? (Analogously: required time order between QFT and measurement of classical function?)

If not, can we ensure that restriction from (inevitable?) collapse of auxiliary qubits does not cripple our computation?

---

Peter Shor has confirmed (below) the problem with auxiliary qubits, requiring to "uncompute" them to fixed values for proper computation process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the factoring algorithm, there are three kinds of qubits. In the OP's notation, there are "input qubits", which start in a superposition of all possible values, and which you eventually take the Fourier transform of. There are "value qubits", in which you compute the function $y^a \pmod{N}$, where $a$ is the value in the input qubits. And there are "auxiliary qubits", which you use as workspace to help do this computation.

In order to make the factoring algorithm work properly, you need to reset all the auxiliary qubits, which started as $|0\rangle$ at the beginning of the computation, to $|0\rangle$ at the end of the computation. This is called "uncomputing" these qubits. (Actually, you can set them to anything you please as long as it is a constant independent of the workings of the algorithm.) Theorems about reversible classical computation ensure that it is possible to do this.

If you reset the auxiliary qubits to $|0\rangle$, then if the environment, or somebody, measures them, nothing is revealed about the computation, and the computation is not "crippled". If you forget to reset them to $|0\rangle$, you probably won't get the right answer, whether or not anybody measures them.

Comment: I think that when the asker writes "auxiliary qubit" that they are referring to the qubits in the second register (the one storing $B^k \text{ mod } R$). Whereas your answer (and the diagram in included in the question) are referring to the extra workspace qubits used when computing the second register when they say "auxiliary". Could you make sure to clarify this distinction, since reseting the second register is not necessary and uncomputing it would be very bad?

Comment: @Craig: Read the original post carefully. He's referring to the extra workspace. *"e.g. we cannot just use OR gate: (x,y)→x or y(x,y)→x or y, and instead we need to use [the Toffoli gate], which is own inverse — but which requires one additional auxiliary qubit."*

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the distinction. I agree that the question appears clear, but based on commenting/chatting with the OP I think they were confused about needing to measure the value qubits (e.g. [in chat they said](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41332093#41332093) "I would say that not measuring the [second register], we should have the original ensemble on input: of all 2^n values, hence period returned by QFT would be 1.")

Comment: @PeterShor, thank you for clarification, I suspected that generally there might be a problem with "wild" auxiliary qubits (analogous to delayed choice QE). Where can I find details about such "uncomputing"? Couldn't we just measure them "in orthogonal basis" - so that the outcome doesn't bring any information about the original qubit? And Craig claims that we don't have to measure output qubits - do you agree? You use this measurement in calculation on [page 17](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9508027.pdf), but commenting that measuring only input would be sufficient.

Comment: Measuring the qubits in the "orthogonal basis" isn't going to work. You need to "uncompute" them. This is discussed briefly on page 9 of my paper, and in much more detail in C. H. Bennett (1973), *Logical reversibility of computation.*

Comment: @JarekDuda That being said, one uncomputation technique does start by measuring in an orthogonal basis. But you also need to do a fixup operation conditional on the measurement result. [Like this](http://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22Bloch%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22Measure%22%5D%2C%5B%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22Bloch%22%5D%5D%7D).

Comment: @CraigGidney, indeed erasing by measuring in orthogonal basis would be also my first choice (like erasing by rotating polarizer in Walborn's DCQE), but Peter Shor says it "isn't gong to work" (?) I have to admit that I have a problem with understanding this "uncompoting" to fixing all auxiliary qubits using a reversible operation (permutation between bit sequences) - the explanation starts with " duplicate the input bits", but no-cloning theorem says it cannot be done - we cannot duplicate a non-fixed qubit (these are after Hadamard) (?) I will have to think about it.

Comment: "Duplicate the input bits" is the explanation for how to fix auxiliary bits in reversible classical computation. They're bits, not qubits. You can duplicate them.

Comment: @JarekDuda He's right that the thing you're describing is not going to work. Just doing a perpendicular measurement doesn't work. You have to also do a fix-up operation conditional on the measurement result before it works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience - everything is clear now.

Comment: +1 Great answer. By the way, I wanted to inform you about the new Stack Exchange site on [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com), which is in private beta at the moment, but will soon go public. In case you're interested, consider joining. We need more expert users like you on that site. :)

Answer (score 6):

*Update*: I originally thought the question was referring to the "value" qubits when the asker said "auxilliary". This answer explains why you don't need to measure the value qubits. For the *actual* auxilliary qubits, which are used as workspace while computing the value qubits, it should also be okay to measure them afterwards but *only because a proper circuit uncomputes them back to 0*.

---

After the value qubits are computed (the ones storing $B^k \text{ mod } R$, not the ones you used as helpers while computing that value!), you can just throw them out. You don't need to measure them or protect them or care for them. Just drop them on the floor. Nothing anyone does to them can hurt the remaining part of the computation. See [this walkthrough of Shor's algorithm](http://algassert.com/post/1718).

Let's do a simple example via my simulator [Quirk](http://algassert.com/quirk). We will initialize a uniform superposition of qubits, and then compute their parity onto an auxiliary qubit (click the image to manipulate the circuit in the simulator):

[image: density matrix before/after parity onto ancilla]

The two green boxes are showing a representation of the density matrix of the top three qubits. We can show that information without disturbing the system because this is a simulator.

Before the parity computation, the qubits are entirely coherent. Afterwards, some of the off-diagonal indicators have disappeared (become zero). This indicates a partial loss of coherence. The states with an even number of ones have been decohered from the states that have an odd number of ones.

Now let's try to use the auxiliary qubit to "mess with" the top three qubits. If we succeed, the density matrix display will show something different. First thing to try is measurement:

[image: density matrix before/after parity onto measured ancilla]

Nothing's different.

Maybe we measured along the wrong axis? Let's rotate the qubit before measuring it:

[image: density matrix before/after parity onto rotate-measured ancilla]

Still no change!

In fact, no matter what we do to the bottom qubit, we can't change the density matrix of the top three qubits. Not without some kind of operation that crosses between them, or some kind of conditioning (e.g. only consider the subset of states where the measurement of the bottom qubit returned a particular result).

If you find this hard to believe, I recommend simply messing around in Quirk for a while, trying to make the densities of the top three qubits change by operating only on the bottom qubit.

---

Another way to confirm that it doesn't matter if you measure the auxilliary qubits is to just do the algebra and check.

The initial state is:

$$|\psi_0\rangle = |0\rangle_{\text{main}} \otimes |0\rangle_{\text{aux}} = |0\rangle_{\text{all}}$$

Then we Hadamard transform the main register:

$$|\psi_1\rangle = H_{\text{main}} |\psi_0\rangle = \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} |k\rangle_{\text{main}} \otimes |0\rangle_{\text{aux}}$$

Note that *I am ignoring normalizing factors*. In the end my argument is going to be based on the proportional size of various cases, instead of absolute size, so this is fine.

Then we pick a random base $B$ apply the modular exponentiation operation, which adds B^k mod R into the auxiliary register where k is the computational basis value of the main register. On an actual machine we'd use some temporary workspace to implement this operation, but that all gets cleaned up so here we only care about the effect on the main and aux registers:

$$M = \Big[ \text{aux} \text{ += } B^{\text{main}} \text{ mod } R \Big]$$

$$|\psi_2\rangle = M \cdot |\psi_1\rangle = \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} |k\rangle_{\text{main}} \otimes |B^k \text{ mod } R\rangle_{\text{aux}}$$

Now we can rewrite $k$ to be in terms of the unknown period of $B^k \text{ mod } R$. We'll use $k = l \cdot m + s$ where $l$ is the period, $s$ is an iteration variable for the offset between 0 and $l$, and $m$ is an iteration variable. With that in mind, we rewrite $|\psi_2\rangle$ as:

$$|\psi_2\rangle = \sum_{m=0}^{\;\;\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1\;\;} \sum_{s=0}^{\text{min}(l, 2^n-lm)-1} |lm+s\rangle_{\text{main}} \otimes |B^{lm+s} \text{ mod } R\rangle_{\text{aux}}$$

Note that $B^{lm+s} = B^{s} \pmod{R}$. Also note that the complicated boundary conditions on $s$ can be simplified by approximating our actual sum with a sum that goes up to the first multiple of $l$ after $2^n$. This is a good approximation as long as $2^n >> l$, which is true since $n$ is chosen such that $2^n > R^2$ and we know that $R > l$. Anyways, after applying that simplification and approximation we get:

$$|\psi_2\rangle \approx \sum_{m=0}^{\;\;\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1\;\;} \sum_{s=0}^{l-1} |lm+s\rangle_{\text{main}} \otimes |B^{s} \text{ mod } R\rangle_{\text{aux}}$$

Because the boundary condition of $s$ doesn't depend on $m$ anymore, we can rearrange the order of the sums. Which gives us:

$$|\psi_2\rangle \approx \sum_{s=0}^{l-1} \left( |B^{s} \text{ mod } R\rangle_{\text{aux}} \otimes \sum_{m=0}^{\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1} |lm+s\rangle_{\text{main}} \right)$$

Now we apply the inverse Fourier transform operation to the main register. Notice that it can be moved from the outside of the sum to the inside:

$$\begin{align}
|\psi_3\rangle
&= \text{QFT}^{\dagger}_{\text{main}} \cdot |\psi_2\rangle
\\
&\approx \text{QFT}^{\dagger}_{\text{main}} \cdot \sum_{s=0}^{l-1} \left( |B^{s} \text{ mod } R\rangle_{\text{aux}} \otimes \sum_{m=0}^{\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1} |lm+s\rangle_{\text{main}} \right)
\\
&= \sum_{s=0}^{l-1} \left( |B^{s} \text{ mod } R\rangle_{\text{aux}} \otimes \sum_{m=0}^{\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1} \text{QFT}^{\dagger}_{\text{main}} \cdot  |lm+s\rangle_{\text{main}} \right)
\end{align}$$

Then expand the definition of the QFT into a sum over a variable $j$, and move that sum outward:

$$\begin{align}
|\psi_3\rangle
&\approx
\sum_{s=0}^{l-1} \left( |B^{s} \text{ mod } R\rangle_{\text{aux}} \otimes \sum_{m=0}^{\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1} \;\; \sum_{j=0}^{2^n-1} |j\rangle_{\text{main}} \cdot \text{exp}(i\tau \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot j \cdot (lm+s)) \right)
\\
&= \sum_{s=0}^{l-1} \left( |B^{s} \text{ mod } R\rangle_{\text{aux}} \otimes \sum_{j=0}^{2^n-1} |j\rangle_{\text{main}} \sum_{m=0}^{\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1} \text{exp}(i\tau \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot j \cdot (lm+s)) \right)
\\
&= \sum_{s=0}^{l-1} \sum_{j=0}^{2^n-1} \left( |B^{s} \text{ mod } R\rangle_{\text{aux}} \otimes |j\rangle_{\text{main}} \sum_{m=0}^{\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1} \text{exp}(i\tau \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot j \cdot (lm+s)) \right)
\end{align}$$

Now we're going to measure the main register. The probability of getting the result $r$ is the total squared magnitude of states where the first register is $r$. Algebraically:

$$\begin{align}
P(r)
&= \sum_{a,b | a=r} \Big| (\langle a |_{\text{main}} \otimes \langle b |_{\text{aux}}) \cdot | \psi_3 \rangle \Big|^2
\\
&= \sum_{b} \Big| (\langle r |_{\text{main}} \otimes \langle b |_{\text{aux}}) \cdot | \psi_3 \rangle \Big|^2
\\
&\approx
\sum_{b} \left| \langle r |_{\text{main}} \langle b |_{\text{aux}} \cdot \sum_{s=0}^{l-1} \sum_{j=0}^{2^n-1} |B^{s} \text{ mod } R\rangle_{\text{aux}} |j\rangle_{\text{main}} \sum_{m=0}^{\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1} \text{exp}(i\tau \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot j \cdot (lm+s)) \right|^2
\end{align}$$

Because all of our basis kets are perpendicular, any summands that fail to satisfy $b=B^s \pmod{R}$ and $r=lm+s$ will be zero'd out. The remaining terms have bras and kets that exactly match, giving an inner product of 1. I'll do this over a few steps because it simplifies the sum considerably:

$$\begin{align}
P(r)
&\approx
\sum_{b} \left| \langle r |_{\text{main}} \langle b |_{\text{aux}} \cdot \sum_{s=0}^{l-1} \sum_{j=0}^{2^n-1} |B^{s} \text{ mod } R\rangle_{\text{aux}} |j\rangle_{\text{main}} \sum_{m=0}^{\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1} \text{exp}(i\tau \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot j \cdot (lm+s)) \right|^2
\\
&=
\sum_{b} \left| \sum_{s=0}^{l-1} \sum_{j=0}^{2^n-1} \langle r |_{\text{main}} \langle b |_{\text{aux}} \cdot |B^{s} \text{ mod } R\rangle_{\text{aux}} |j\rangle_{\text{main}} \sum_{m=0}^{\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1} \text{exp}(i\tau \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot j \cdot (lm+s)) \right|^2
\\
&=
\sum_{b} \left| \sum_{s=0}^{l-1} \sum_{j=0}^{2^n-1} \langle r | j\rangle_{\text{main}} \langle b | B^{s} \text{ mod } R\rangle_{\text{aux}} \sum_{m=0}^{\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1} \exp(i\tau \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot j \cdot (lm+s)) \right|^2
\\
&=
\sum_{s=0}^{l-1} \left| \sum_{j=0}^{2^n-1} \langle r | j\rangle_{\text{main}} \sum_{m=0}^{\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1} \exp(i\tau \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot j \cdot (lm+s)) \right|^2
\\
&=
\sum_{s=0}^{l-1} \left| \sum_{m=0}^{\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1} \exp(i\tau \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot r \cdot (lm+s)) \right|^2
\end{align}$$

Now we're getting somewhere. The next thing to do is get rid of that pesky $s$. Factor the $s$ component out of the inner sum, which lets you factor it out of the squared-magnitude, at which point you realize it contributes nothing and the sum can turn into a multiplication by $l$:

$$\begin{align}
P(r)
&\approx
\sum_{s=0}^{l-1} \left| \sum_{m=0}^{\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1} \exp(i\tau \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot r \cdot (lm+s)) \right|^2
\\
&=
\sum_{s=0}^{l-1} \left| \sum_{m=0}^{\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1} \exp(i\tau \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot r \cdot lm) \cdot \exp(i\tau \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot r \cdot s) \right|^2
\\
&=
\sum_{s=0}^{l-1} \left| \exp(i\tau \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot r \cdot s) \sum_{m=0}^{\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1} \exp(i\tau \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot r \cdot lm) \right|^2
\\
&=
\sum_{s=0}^{l-1} \big| \exp(i\tau \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot r \cdot s) \big|^2 \left| \sum_{m=0}^{\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1} \exp(i\tau \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot r \cdot lm) \right|^2
\\
&=
\sum_{s=0}^{l-1} \left| \sum_{m=0}^{\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1} \exp(i\tau \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot r \cdot lm) \right|^2
\\
&=
l \cdot \left| \sum_{m=0}^{\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1} \exp(i\tau \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot rl \cdot m) \right|^2
\end{align}$$

Nearly there. To make the structure of the sum blatant, we extract a variable $\omega = \exp(i\tau rl / 2^{n})$:

$$\begin{align}
P(r)
&\approx
l \cdot \left| \sum_{m=0}^{\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1} \exp(i\tau \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot rl \cdot m) \right|^2
\\
&=
l \cdot \left| \sum_{m=0}^{\lceil 2^n / l \rceil-1} \omega^{m} \right|^2 \text{  where } \omega = \exp(i\tau r l / 2^{n})
\end{align}$$

The inner sum will be largest when all of its terms point in the same direction, i.e. when $\omega \approx 1$. Which means $\exp(i\tau rl / 2^{n}) \approx 1$, which in turn means that $2^{-n} r l$ is nearly an integer $d$. Rewrite $2^{-n} r l \approx d$ and you get:

$$r \approx 2^n \cdot \frac{d}{l}$$

In other words, if the period is $l$ then the values you are most likely to measure are placed near multiples of $2^n / l$. In practice you recover $l$ by solving "which possible multiple was my measurement nearest to?".

I leave it as an exercise for the reader to work out exactly how much more likely you are to measure values of $r$ that give values of $\omega$ close to 1.

Comment: A small self contained example might help.

Comment: Sure there is no FTL (or back in time) communication - like in EPR or Delayed Choice QE, there is no way to actually send information this way. However, Shor uses the fact that measurement of classical function affects the computation (by restricting ensemble, delay seems unimportant?), so analogous effect should be true for auxiliary qbits (?), as physically situation is practically the same. Just releasing them into environment should collapse them - what seems analogous to measurement (?) Maybe we should e.g. shoot such photons into space, such that they could fly uncollapsed infinitely?

Comment: @DanielSank Done.

Comment: @JarekDuda It's fine if they collapse. All of the decoherence damage they can do was already done by computing them in the first place. Collapsing them won't do any more damage to the state of the remaining qubits. I have rewritten my answer.

Comment: @CraigGidney, so why measuring/collapsing the qbits of classical function influences the original ensemble, but it is not true for auxiliary qbits? From physical point of view they seem nearly the same: used in gates on the way - what is the difference between them? Maybe collapsing these auxiliary qbits is one of the reasons of the problem with decoherence ? Can we ensure that qbit will never collapse, e.g. by shooting such photon into space?

Comment: Ok, I think I understood (?) this crucial difference between measurement of classical function qbits, and collapse of auxiliary qbits: in measurement we use the proper basis (e.g. z axis), while collapse ("just throw them out") corresponds to measurement in a random basis. If so, couldn't we reduce decoherence rate by measuring auxiliary qbits in an independent basis (like x/y axis) ?

Comment: @JarekDuda You're mixing up after-the-fact and before-the-fact concepts. No measurement you plan to do do on the auxiliary qubits can affect the predicted probability of the algorithm succeeding. But after you do such a  measurement you may have new information that updates your prediction, so you know if the algorithm will succeed or not. This implies a changed state in the initial qubits: maybe a bad one, maybe a good one, maybe neutrl. But the set of possible state changes is balanced such that doing the measurement can't be expected to hurt or hinder the algorithm on average. It's neutral.

Comment: @CraigGidney, even https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor's_algorithm says that we measure both QFT and output (of classical function), but use only the first one in further calculation. Measurement itself of output bits influences the behavior (similar to delayed choice QE) ... and auxiliary bits come from the same gates as output qbits, so their measurement should also affect computation.

Comment: @JarekDuda Where does it say you *have* to measure the output? For example, the circuit diagram in that article simply ends the ancilla wire because it doesn't matter anymore. In step 4 they say you get a result z from measuring the output wire, but they never actually use z or say you really need it. You don't.

Comment: @JarekDuda Read this: http://algassert.com/post/1718

Comment: @CraigGidney, Point 4 of quantum part of this Wikipedia article starts with: "Perform a measurement. We obtain some outcome y in the input register and z in the output register."

Comment: @JarekDuda Yes, but they don't use z. They happen to measure it, but never use it and never say you *must* measure it.

Comment: @CraigGidney, indeed as I have previously written, they measure output z, but don't use it in further calculation (analogously to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_choice_quantum_eraser ). If you wouldn't measure it (what fixes z), in input you would have the original superposition of all 2^n possibilities, and so QFT would say that the period is 1. To get nontrivial period in QFT you have to fix on a single output z (formula in point 4 of Wikipedia article), what is done by measuring z.

Comment: @JarekDuda The delayed choice quantum eraser is not a valid analogy for this situation, because in that experiment they *use* the ancilla's measurement result (to group the other measurements). Shor's algorithm doesn't use z, so it doesn't matter if you measure z. Measuring z does nothing that helps, and nothing that hinders. It. does. not. matter. if. you. measure. it.

Comment: @CraigGidney, all sources I have found, e.g. [original Shor's article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9508027.pdf), or [this one](http://tph.tuwien.ac.at/~oemer/doc/quprog/node18.html), have calculations using the fact that we have measured output, what restricts ensemble on input to periodic one, which period is found by QFT. It doesn't seem to make sense without measuring output, but as you claim otherwise, please provide some source, calculation to support your claims?

Comment: @JarekDuda Here is [a simulation in Quirk](http://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22setR%22%2C%22arg%22%3A55%7D%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22setB%22%2C%22arg%22%3A26%7D%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputA10%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22*BToAmodR6%22%5D%2C%5B%22QFT%E2%80%A010%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance10%22%5D%5D%7D) showing that the frequency peaks are present even without measuring the ancilla.

Comment: @CraigGidney, I don't know details of your simulation, and I believe it ignores many auxiliary qbits required to calculate B^A mod R, which is a complex arithmetic operation. Could you cite any non-yours source? Or just give straightforward calculation: take sum_y |y> |f(y)>, measure only y, and show that it still behaves like being restricted to some fixed z=f(y)? As different 'z' would probably result in different periods, period for which z your QFT would give?

Comment: Regarding delayed choice quantum erasure, see [Walborn's realization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0106078.pdf) - manipulating polarizer on one path, we get or not information about the slit on the second path - we can choose between classical and interfering behavior for photons on the other path. This seems similar to measuring or not output qbits in Shor - what can affect behavior on the second  path.

Comment: @JarekDuda I added a worked out example. I expect you to work through it and understand the whole thing, because it takes a lot of time to do. This is why simulators are so much nicer.

Comment: @JarekDuda The paper you referenced is just another example of an experiment that cares about the auxiliary qubits because it *uses the result of measuring them*. In particular, they group the measurements of the main photon based on the associated auxiliary measurement. Shor's algorithm doesn't do anything like that, which is why it can simply discard the auxiliary qubits without caring what happens to them.